# Pagination in CodeIgniter 2.1.0 with query in model

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Excuse me Master... I am nubie in codeigniter (2 month)

I want ask about pagination in codeigniter 2.1.0 where the results of query from model

**this is my model:**

[image]

**Here is my Controller**

[image]

And the last here is my config.php

```
$config['limit_data'] = '10';
```

Need your advice master :)

Thanks for your time.

UPDATE :
For Text : http://palinghoki.com/codeigniter-pagination.txt

Comment: Is there any problem for u? but what about last three view you loaded.

Comment: Can you give me one good reason that you are using Codeigniter version 2.1.0 instead of the latest one? Really the only thing that you have to change is the system folder.

Comment: @vijay4vijju : yes, in view all data load (12 records) although have set 'limit_data' = 10, the three view the last I just header and footer except bg_home is body to reload from my query (ListCabangKaryawan)

Comment: @JohnSkoumbourdis : because it's my first time I learning codeigniter :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two functions for it. First, to count the total files a user has, and the second to get the results pagination wise. What you are doing wrong here is that you are fetching all the records in a single query without the limit.

Follow [`my previous`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851771/pagination-and-search-displaying-all-records-on-each-page/19853786#19853786) answer on this.

**Edit:**

```
function ListCabangKaryawan()
{
    return $q = $this->db->query("select b.branch_code,b.branch_name,count(bk.status_karyawan) as jml_karyawan,
        SUM(B.ANGGOTA+B.DANRU+B.WADANRU+B.SECWAN+B.PKD+B.DANKI+B.ADMIN+B.RESEPSIONIS+B.LIDIK+B.ASS_CHIEF+B.CHIEF+B.KORDINATOR) AS jml_komposisi
        from branch b left join biodata_karyawan bk
        on b.branch_code=bk.branch_code
        and bk.status_karyawan='Aktif'
        where b.status='a'
        group by b.branch_code order by b.branch_code")->num_rows();
}

function ListCabangKaryawanByLimit($limit, $offset = 0){
    if( !$offset ){
        $offset = 0;
    }
    return $q = $this->db->query("select b.branch_code,b.branch_name,count(bk.status_karyawan) as jml_karyawan,
                SUM(B.ANGGOTA+B.DANRU+B.WADANRU+B.SECWAN+B.PKD+B.DANKI+B.ADMIN+B.RESEPSIONIS+B.LIDIK+B.ASS_CHIEF+B.CHIEF+B.KORDINATOR) AS jml_komposisi
                from branch b left join biodata_karyawan bk
                on b.branch_code=bk.branch_code
                and bk.status_karyawan='Aktif'
                where b.status='a'
                group by b.branch_code order by b.branch_code limit {$offset}, {$limit}")->result_array();
}
    function index()
{
    $cek = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    $cek2 = $this->session->userdata('level');

    if(!empty($cek))
    {
        $d['judul'] = 'ERP - '.$this->config->item('nama_perusahaan');
        $d['nama_perusahaan'] = $this->config->item('nama_perusahaan');
        $d['alamat_perusahaan'] = $this->config->item('alamat_perusahaan');
        $d['lisensi'] = $this->config->item('lisensi_app');

        $bc['menu'] = $this->load->view('app/menu', '', true);
        $bc['bio'] = $this->load->view('app/bio', $bc, true);

        $limit   = 20; //say 20 items to show per page.
        $offset  = $this->uri->segment(3); //this is the offset to use in query

        $config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'karyawan_front/index/';
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->app_model->ListCabangKaryawan(); 
        $config['per_page'] = $limit;           
        $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
        $config['first_link'] = 'Awal';
        $config['last_link'] = 'Akhir';
        $config['next_link'] = 'Selanjutnya';
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Sebelumnya';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $bc["paginator"] =$this->pagination->create_links();    

        //tampilan data
        $bc['dt_cabang'] = $this->app_model->ListCabangKaryawanByLimit($limit, $offset);
        $q_total = $this->app_model->TotalCabang();
        if($q_total->num_rows()>0)
        {
            foreach($q_total->result() as $w)
            {
                $bc['total'] = $w->total;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $bc['total'] = '0';
        }                           

        $this->load->view('global/bg_top',$d);
        $this->load->view('karyawan_front/bg_home',$bc);
        $this->load->view('global/bg_footer',$d);
    }
    else
    {
        $st = $this->session->userdata('status');
        if($st=='a')
        {
            header('location:'.base_url().'app');
        }
        else
        {
            header('location:'.base_url().'front');
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

```
if(isset( $dt_cabang ) && is_array( $dt_cabang ) && count( $dt_cabang ) > 0 )
{
    foreach($dt_cabang as $db)
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $no; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $db['branch_name']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $db['branch_code']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $db['jml_karyawan']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $db['jml_komposisi']; ?></td>
    <td><?php 
    $jml_karyawan = $db['jml_karyawan'];
    $jml_komposisi = $db['jml_komposisi'];
    $kekurangan_personil = $jml_karyawan - $jml_komposisi;
    if($kekurangan_personil < 0)
    {
        echo '<font color="red">' . $kekurangan_personil . '</font>';
    }
    else if($kekurangan_personil == 0)
    {
        echo '<font color="blue">COMPLITE</font>';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo '<font color="green">OVER BUDGET :' . $kekurangan_personil . '</font>';
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: you forgot to mention the offset.

Comment: the first thanks for your response guy, but if I read your link that's your answer, codeigniter in used 2.1.4 ? what is different?. can you write code from my code at above :)

Comment: update your question.dont post image as cause I cant copy the code.

Comment: @Nil'z : sorry Nil, I have try to write code but failed (my mistake cant understand to write code at above). so here the link you can show  model and controller : http://palinghoki.com/codeigniter-pagination.txt

Comment: Edited the above try once again.

Comment: @Nil'z : Thanks Guy, I have try your code, but in 'View' return error "Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in D:\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\csi\application\views\karyawan_front\bg_home.php on line 76"   this is my View update at the same link : http://palinghoki.com/codeigniter-pagination.txt

Comment: the line 76 is 'if($dt_cabang->num_rows()>0)'

Comment: woww... that's great... thanks alot of for your patience and answer... I have 3 days but always failed... you are very handsome guys... :)